# Algorithm to calculate sum of points for groups with varying member count

Tags: algorithm, math

Let's start with an example. In Harry Potter, Hogwarts has 4 houses with students sorted into each house. The same happens on my website and I don't know how many users are in each house. It could be 20 in one house 50 in another and 100 in the third and fourth.

Now, each student can earn points on the website and at the end of the year, the house with the most points will win.
But it's not fair to "only" do a sum of the points, as the house with a 100 students will have a much higher chance to win, as they have more users to earn points. So I need to come up with an algorithm which is fair.

You can see an example here: https://worldofpotter.dk/points
What I do now is to sum all the points for a house, and then divide it by the number of users who have earned more than 10 points. This is still not fair, though.

Any ideas on how to make this calculation more fair?

Things we need to take into account:
* The percent of users earning points in each house
* Few users earning LOTS of points
* Many users earning FEW points (It's not bad earning few points. It still counts towards the total points of the house)

Link to MySQL dump(with users, houses and points): https://worldofpotter.dk/wop_points_example.sql
Link to CSV of points only: https://worldofpotter.dk/points.csv

Comment: compute mean value per house?

Comment: use the median value?

Comment: Median wouldn't work, if the house has 10 users earning 1 point and 1 user earning 10000 points, then the median would be 1, but the house still has a lot of points.

Comment: What's wrong with average? It seems like the best fit unless you care about even distribution across the house then perhaps geometric mean would be better for you.

Comment: @scsimon I **guess** the weak point in averages is, you can create dummy players for the opponents houses, having few points (zero? one?) and effectively lower opponents' houses overall score.

Comment: Good point @MartinMilichovsky but the web site should handle this with unique logins, cookie attribution, etc. I think if a player is able to do what you are saying, there will never be any great method to make the play fair.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. It's more about the design of an incentive. "Fair" in the sense you're asking is about a sense of fairness in a social setting.

Comment: As long as you don't give a proper definition of fair, it will be hard to take this into account.

Comment: I think that the bullets under "Things we need to take into account" is pointers to what is fair.
Basicly i'm also look for pointers on what 'fair' is.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based in addition to being too broad, and should be closed as such.

Comment: I agree. Fair is completely up to an opinion... One might think it is fair to make everyone a winner... this is fair because we do not know if the users who participated less, or scored less were under more or less stress. Do we know the age of the participants? Do we know the social upbringing of the participants?

I for one believe that if it is a team game, and the contest is per house... then do your best to make the teams/houses the same size, and whichever house scores the most points win... end of story.... But, then again, others may not feel the same way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use something like `Discounted Cumulative Gain` which is used for measuring the effectiveness of search engines.

The concept is as it follows:

```
FUNCTION evalHouseScore (0_INDEXED_SORTED_ARRAY scores):
    score = 0;
    FOR (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++):
        score += scores[i]/log2(i);
    END_FOR
    RETURN score;
END_FUNCTION;
```

This must be somehow modified as this way of measuring focuses on the first result. As this is subjective you should decide on your the way you would modify it. Below I'll post the code which some constants which you should try with different values:

```
FUNCTION evalHouseScore (0_INDEXED_SORTED_ARRAY scores):
    score = 0;
    FOR (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++):
        score += scores[i]/log2(i+K);
    END_FOR
    RETURN L*score;
END_FUNCTION
```

Consider changing the logarithm.

**Tests:**

```
    int[] g = new int[] {758,294,266,166,157,132,129,116,111,88,83,74,62,60,60,52,43,40,28,26,25,24,18,18,17,15,15,15,14,14,12,10,9,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1};
    int[] s = new int[] {612,324,301,273,201,182,176,139,130,121,119,114,113,113,106,86,77,76,65,62,60,58,57,54,54,42,42,40,36,35,34,29,28,23,22,19,17,16,14,14,13,11,11,9,9,8,8,7,7,7,6,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1};
    int[] h = new int[] {813,676,430,382,360,323,265,235,192,170,107,103,80,70,60,57,43,41,21,17,15,15,12,10,9,9,9,8,8,6,6,6,4,4,4,3,2,2,2,1,1,1};
    int[] r = new int[] {1398,1009,443,339,242,215,210,205,177,168,164,144,144,92,85,82,71,61,58,47,44,33,21,19,18,17,12,11,11,9,8,7,7,6,5,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1};
```

The output is for different offsets:

```
1182
1543
1847
2286

904
1231
1421
1735

813
1120
1272
1557
```

Comment: I've added some test data for you to play around with :)

Comment: What would K and L be in your code?

Comment: These tests are for `L=naturallogarithm(2)`, `K = 8, 20, 30`. The larger the K is, the more first results are significant. L is just to divide/multiply all results by the same number.

Comment: To understand it better, count 100 divided by log2 of 2, 3, 4...100 and see how it changes. You can also try with floor of the result. Play with it!

Comment: I like it! Looks like it takes everything into account.

Comment: @Danielss89 how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some sort of constraint between the houses may need to be introduced. I might suggest finding the person that earned the most points out of all the houses and using it as the denominator when rolling up the scores. This will guarantee the max value of a user's contribution is 1, then all the scores for a house can be summed and then divided by the number of users to normalize the house's score. That should give you a reasonable comparison. It does introduce issues with low numbers of users in a house that are high achievers in which you may want to consider lower limits to the number of house members. Another technique may be to introduce handicap scores for users to balance the scales. The algorithm will most likely flex over time based on the data you receive. To keep it fair it will take some responsive action after the initial iteration. Players can come up with some creative ways to make scoring systems work for them. Here is some pseudo-code in PHP that you may use:

```
<?php
$mostPointsEarned; // Find the user that earned the most points

$houseScores = [];

foreach ($houses as $house) {

    $numberOfUsers = 0;
    $normalizedScores = [];

    foreach ($house->getUsers() as $user) {

        $normalizedScores[] = $user->getPoints() / $mostPointsEarned;
        $numberOfUsers++;
    }

    $houseScores[] = array_sum($normalizedScores) / $numberOfUsers;
}

var_dump($houseScores);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given any examples on what should be preferred state, and what are situations against which you want to be immune. (3,2,1,1 compared to 5,2 etc.)

It's also a pity you haven't provided us the dataset in some nice way to play.

```
scala> val input = Map( // as seen on 2016-09-09 14:10 UTC on https://worldofpotter.dk/points
  'G' -> Seq(758,294,266,166,157,132,129,116,111,88,83,74,62,60,60,52,43,40,28,26,25,24,18,18,17,15,15,15,14,14,12,10,9,5,5,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,1,1),
  'S' -> Seq(612,324,301,273,201,182,176,139,130,121,119,114,113,113,106,86,77,76,65,62,60,58,57,54,54,42,42,40,36,35,34,29,28,23,22,19,17,16,14,14,13,11,11,9,9,8,8,7,7,7,6,4,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1),
  'H' -> Seq(813,676,430,382,360,323,265,235,192,170,107,103,80,70,60,57,43,41,21,17,15,15,12,10,9,9,9,8,8,6,6,6,4,4,4,3,2,2,2,1,1,1),
  'R' -> Seq(1398,1009,443,339,242,215,210,205,177,168,164,144,144,92,85,82,71,61,58,47,44,33,21,19,18,17,12,11,11,9,8,7,7,6,5,4,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,1)
) // and the results on the website were: 1. R 1951, 2. H 1859, 3. S 990, 4. G 954
```

Here is what I thought of:

```
def singleValuedScore(individualScores: Seq[Int]) = individualScores
  .sortBy(-_) // sort from most to least
  .zipWithIndex // add indices e.g. (best, 0), (2nd best, 1), ...
  .map { case (score, index) => score * (1 + index) } // here is the 'logic'
  .max

input.mapValues(singleValuedScore)

res: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = 
       Map(G -> 1044, 
           S -> 1590, 
           H -> 1968, 
           R -> 2018)
```

The overall positions would be:

1. Ravenclaw with 2018 aggregated points
2. Hufflepuff with 1968
3. Slytherin with 1590
4. Gryffindor with 1044

Which corresponds to the ordering on that web: 1. R 1951, 2. H 1859, 3. S 990, 4. G 954.

The algorithms output is maximal product of `score of user` and `rank of the user` within a house.

- This measure is not affected by "long-tail" of users having low score compared to the *active* ones.
- There are no hand-set cutoffs or thresholds.
- You could experiment with the *rank* attribution (`score * index` or `score * Math.sqrt(index)` or `score / Math.log(index + 1)` ...)

Comment: I've added a dataset exported from my database :)

Comment: @NavidVafaei edited, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the fair measure is the number of points divided by the number of house members. Since you have the number of points, **the exercise boils down to estimate the number of members.**

We are in short supply of data here as the only hint we have on member counts is the answers on the website. This makes us vulnerable to manipulation, members can trick us into underestimating their numbers. If the suggested estimation method to "count respondents with points >10" would be known, houses would only encourage the best to do the test to hide members from our count. This is a real problem and the only thing I will do about it is to present a "manipulation indicator".

How could we then estimate member counts? Since we do not know anything other than test results, **we have to infer the propensity to do the test from the actual results**. And we have little other to assume than that we would have **a symmetric result distribution (of the logarithm of the points) if all members tested.** Now let's say the strong would-be respondents are more likely to actually test than weak would-be respondents. Then we could measure the extra dropout ratio for the weak by comparing the numbers of respondents in corresponding weak and strong test-point quantiles.

To be specific, of the 205 answers, there are 27 in the worst half of the overall weakest quartile, while 32 in the strongest half of the best quartile. So an extra 5 respondents of the very weakest have dropped out from an assumed all-testing symmetric population, and to adjust for this, we are going to estimate member count from this quantile by multiplying the number of responses in it by 32/27=about 1.2. Similarly, we have 29/26 for the next less-extreme half quartiles and 41/50 for the two mid quartiles.

So we would estimate members by simply counting the number of respondents but multiplying the number of respondents in the weak quartiles mentioned above by 1.2, 1.1 and 0.8 respectively. If however any result distribution within a house would be conspicuously skewed, which is not the case now, we would have to suspect manipulation and re-design our member count.

For the sample at hand however, these adjustments to member counts are minor, and yields the same house ranks as from just counting the respondents without adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

I got myself to amuse me a little bit with your question and some python programming with some random generated data. As some people mentioned in the comments you need to define what is fairness. If as you said you don't know the number of people in each of the houses, you can use the number of participations of each house, thus you motivate participation (it can be unfair depending on the number of people of each house, but as you said you don't have this data on the first place).
The important part of the code is the following.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint  # import random int
# initialize random seed
np.random.seed(4)

houses = ["Gryffindor","Slytherin", "Hufflepuff", "Ravenclaw"]

houses_points = []
# generate random data for each house
for _ in houses:
    # houses_points.append(randint(0, 100, randint(60,100)))
    houses_points.append(randint(0, 50, randint(2,10)))

# count participation
houses_participations = []
houses_total_points = []
for house_id in xrange(len(houses)):
    houses_total_points.append(np.sum(houses_points[house_id]))
    houses_participations.append(len(houses_points[house_id]))
# sum the total number of participations
total_participations = np.sum(houses_participations)

# proposed model with weighted total participation points
houses_partic_points = []
for house_id in xrange(len(houses)):
    tmp = houses_total_points[house_id]*houses_participations[house_id]/total_participations
    houses_partic_points.append(tmp)
```

The results of this method are the following:

```
House       Points per Participant
Gryffindor: [46  5  1 40]
Slytherin:  [ 8  9 39 45 30 40 36 44 38]
Hufflepuff: [42  3  0 21 21  9 38 38]
Ravenclaw:  [ 2 46]

House       Number of Participations per House
Gryffindor: 4
Slytherin:  9
Hufflepuff: 8
Ravenclaw:  2

House       Total Points
Gryffindor: 92
Slytherin:  289
Hufflepuff: 172
Ravenclaw:  48

House       Points weighted by a participation factor
Gryffindor: 16
Slytherin:  113
Hufflepuff: 59
Ravenclaw:  4
```

You'll find the complete file with printing results here (https://gist.github.com/silgon/5be78b1ea0b55a20d90d9ec3e7c515e5).

Answer (score 0):

You should enter some more rules to define the fairness.

**Idea 1**
You could set up the rule that anyone has to earn at least 10 points to enter the competition.
Then you can calculate the average points for each house.
Positive: Everyone needs to show some motivation.

**Idea 2**
Another approach would be to set the rule that from each house only the 10 best students will count for the competition.
Positive: Easy rule to calculate the points.
Negative: Students might become uninterested if they see they can't reach the top 10 places of their house.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, your problem is diveded in a few points:

- The best thing to do would be to re - assignate the player in the different Houses so that each House has the same number of players. (as explain by @navid-vafaei)

If you don't want to do that because you believe that it may affect your game popularity with player whom are in House that they don't want because you can change the choice of the Sorting Hat at least in the movie or books.

In that case, you can sum the point of the student's house and divide by the number of students. You may just remove the number of student with a very low score. You may remove as well the student with a very low activity because students whom skip school might be fired.

The most important part for me n your algorithm is weather or not you give points for all valuables things:
In the Harry Potter's story, the students earn point on the differents subjects they chose at school and get point according to their score.
At the end of the year, there is a special award event. At that moment, the Director gave points for valuable things which cannot be evaluated in the subject at school suche as the qualites (bravery for example).